# com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()Ljava/util/stream/Collector;

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, webdriver

I know there are few similar questions, but they are mostly outdated and does not help to resolve my problem.

Trying to run my first selenium test using selenium version 4.2.0 and its my first time to use maven but it always throw this error and I did all I have to overcome this but still don't know how to solve or where is the issue.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()Ljava/util/stream/Collector;
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilitiesUtils.makeW3CSafe(CapabilitiesUtils.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilitiesUtils.makeW3CSafe(CapabilitiesUtils.java:72)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:267)
    at java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Collections.java:4719)
    at java.util.Collections$2.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:4727)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.DriverCommand.NEW_SESSION(DriverCommand.java:65)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:247)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:114)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:94)
    at com.google.ChromeDriverDemo.main(ChromeDriverDemo.java:15)
```

here is my POM file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.google</groupId>
  <artifactId>Selenium.test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>Selenium.test</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1</version>
      <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.12.4</version>
      <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
      <type>maven-plugin</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      <version>31.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a tipical jar conflict problem. selenium-java include a guava dependence.

you can use mavenhelper or `mvn dependency:tree` command help you analysis.

try to exclude `guava` dependence